# react external javascript integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I'm tring to merge 2 projects i found:
https://github.com/danxfisher/MeetEasier
and
this page https://tympanus.net/Development/Interactive3DMallMap/

i've done the changes in the react project meeteasier and included the html parts from interactivemallmap(with my little react  abd nodejs knowledge) . I have problems on calling the javascript from main.js(interactivemallmap).
Here is the problem:
The first time i load the page with the chromedev i see that in the main.js it gets the values but when i recall the functions that values are null:
original main.js start like this and dot work:

```
  ;(function(window) {
     ...
     mall = document.querySelector('.mall'),
     ...
     pins = [].slice.call(mallLevelsEl.querySelectorAll('.map__space')),
     ....
     pins.forEach(function(pin) {
                var contentItem = contentEl.querySelector('.content__item[data- space="' + pin.getAttribute('data-space') + '"]');

            pin.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                //if( !isOpenContentArea ) {
                    classie.add(contentItem, 'content__item--hover');
            //}
            });
     ....
     })(window);
```

i've tried with the $(document).ready(function(){ instead of ;(function(window) {
but it is not working or better: in the first page load the it gets its value, but after when i pass over with the mouse and the event mouseenter triggers all the values are undefined

I think this is not the right approach but how do i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough code to fully understand what is going on, but seeing that you're trying to merge two big projects with different codebases, if I were you I should take it slow, and take some steps back.

**Your problem:**

The main problem is that, to use React, you should first have a fundemental understanding of what it is doing under the hood.

You're trying to implement jQuery (a DOM library) with React, however, this will not work this easily, because React works with something that's called a virtual DOM, and it does not have access to the regular DOM nodes unless specifically ordered to do so (using `findDOMNode` from the `react-dom` package handles this for example).

**What you should do:**

Please read the docs first:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html

Then, after you understand React, try implementing the SVG maps in it, step by step.

**Just a small insight:**

Rendering SVG in your `render` method, or try rebuilding it with D3 (https://d3js.org/) for example, just a suggestion on how to handle complex SVG.

You should handle most logic that's from `main.js` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle, assuming you're going to need to access the map nodes.

Comment: Tanks for the answer, I have uploaded a video here maybe you understand better my problem: https://youtu.be/N85pJ5w0hz0  so if i understand well, the page that is rendered(dom) is not accessible to a js library client side? i have to put all the functions translated to react from main.js into componentDidMount? i read some docs on react js but i did not understand that i cant use some js libraries like i do it in a simple index.html file

Comment: No, React is also client side, and works well with lots of different JS libraries, but not with libraries that work with the DOM. React doesn't work with the DOM directly. 

First thing you should do is learn React before you want to work with it, try using `create-react-app`. And no, these days, most Javascript is loaded in through modules using Node.js, you can't just simply load stuff in through script tags because of the way most Front-end development has changed, start with this: https://wesbos.com/javascript-modules/